# Django - Automatic Login After Sign Up With Custom User Model

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am trying to automatically login a user after signing up using a Django module that implements modal forms and a custom user model that uses email instead of username. For some reason on trying to authenticate the user using the authenticate method, it returns None and the value of new_user is None. Could this be due to the custom user model or the module I am using?

```
class SignUpView(BSModalCreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'
    success_message = 'Success: Sign up succeeded. You can now Log in.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('plan:plan')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        valid = super(SignUpView, self).form_valid(form)
        email, password = form.cleaned_data.get('email'), form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        new_user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        login(self.request, new_user)
        return valid
```

Comment: what mixins does your `BSModalCreateView` class implements?

Comment: `BSModalCreateView` is part of the django-bootstrap-modal-forms module I'm using, it inherits `generic.CreateView`, `SuccessMessageMixin` and one of the module's mixins `PassRequestMixin`

Comment: And what does CustomUserCreationForm look like?